# App device token not being saved on Parse, even when didRegisterForRemote... is being called

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've had an app with Push notifications set up and working for months.  Device tokens were being saved to Parse from the App Delegate as normal but 2 weeks ago, new installs aren't getting their device tokens being saved.

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    NSLog(@"registered for push");
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
           NSLog(@"good");
       } else {
           NSLog(@"error"); 
       }
   }];
```

}

This delegate method is being called every time when a user accepts push notifications, and it will console log "good" on completion, but when I go to Parse the deviceToken column is empty.

Any idea on what could be going wrong?  It's stopped on iOS and Android.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this has the answer you are looking for:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982216/get-device-token-for-push-notifications-after-app-was-deleted?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982216/get-device-token-for-push-notifications-after-app-was-deleted?rq=1

Comment: thanks Jeremy.  The app does call it every time, which is how the app delegate method is called every time on launch.  And it still doesn't save to Parse.