# Updating Parse Installation for app with parse class deleted

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, notifications

I created an app and integrated Parse Notification. Due to a glitch, there were unnecessary notification being sent to all users. To stop this immediately, I deleted the installation class after applying filter, but realized that it deleted all my parse installation from Core.

Basically, there are no devices on my parse console now and no notifications are being sent at all.

I wish to provide an app update where I can get the parse to register the devices again.

Can someone please advise how I can do this.

Comment: For the iOS side take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16982762/4080860

Answer (score 1):

It is quite a big mistake to delete the installation class instead of preventing Push notifications in the Cloud or even deleting the Push certificates. When a user registers his device with Parse backend for the first time, the SDK generates a unique `installationId` and caches it locally on the device. As far as I know, this will prevent your users to register again (even if you send a new app update) with the backend UNLESS they delete the whole app and reinstall it to get rid of that cached id.